# I need to hide set the vertical line for gridcontrol

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, devexpress

I need to set the vertical line of the column headers in gridcontrol.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://$SITEURL$/help/mcve) that demonstrates 
your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this styling in your window resource

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Transparent">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ContentHeader" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Padding="5,5,5,0" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
</Style>
```

Comment: `GridViewColumnHeader` is meant to set style for Grid Control column header. In the question you mention you need to set vertical lines which will be done by the border control.

Comment: I might say something wrong. What I need is to hide the vertical line

Comment: Grid would not have gridlines by default! You will need to set ShowGridLines to show them. The image you have uploaded do not seem to have vertical lines either.

Comment: I am using the DevExpress control gridControl, the diagram is what I want, I do not know if you have used it

Comment: Change `Appearance` in property window from design for `HeaderPanel`  option `VertLine`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
<DataGrid   ItemsSource="{Binding  Path=CardGroupSecond}">

        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Type">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Background="Red" Width="40" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Text="{Binding Path=SlotTypeValue}"                                                                         
                                                                         >
                            <TextBox.LayoutTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </TextBox.LayoutTransform>
                        </TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Slot">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Content="{Binding Path=Slot}"                                                                         
                                                                         >
                            <Button.LayoutTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Button.LayoutTransform>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: It's not what I use  gridcontrol , maybe I didn't describe it clearly. I need to hide the vertical line of the column head